# JTree : modify apperance regardless of L&F

Tags: java, swing, jtree, look-and-feel

I've got a JTree which I'm trying to modify it so that the actual selection area for any selected node will extend from the very left of the JTree to the very right of the JTree.

Most examples on the web talks about extending BasicTreeUI. From there you just modify the methods that determine selection area, and that's it. However, this will require that the JTree - regardless of which platform it runs on - will use that implementation. I won't really be able to take advantage of the various UI implementations that target specific platforms as I always will be using BasicTreeUI (and not the Metal, Windows or Aquia implementations).

What I ideally would like to be able to do is to take whatever implementation of BasicTreeUI that is currently installed on the JTree and wrap it in a custom wrapper of mine which extends BasicTreeUI. From there I would override all methods and delegate to the wrapped UI, and do my own implementation of a few methods where required to recalculate the node selection area. However, most methods on BasicTreeUI is protected,
so I can really do this.

Not sure how to get around this...any ideas would be welcome!

Comment: "However, most methods on BasicTreeUI is protected" - If they're protected then you can override them, do you mean `private`?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could override `setUI` and wrap the provided UI in your custom tree UI, like so:

```
@Override
public void setUI(TreeUI ui) {
    super.setUI(new MyCustomTreeUI(ui));
}
```

Another option to consider is looking into providing/setting tree UI properties in the global `UIManager`. I believe that the platform-specific tree UIs will ask the global `UIManager` for property values and configure themselves accordingly - perhaps you could simply do something like `UIManager.put("Tree.selectionWidth", 100)`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, it won't really work because MyCustomTreeUI won't be able to override the required methods of the provided ui instance as they are protected. Specifically, I am looking to modify whatever dimensions the BasicTreeUI#createNodeDimensions() method which determines the node size.

Comment: You can override `protected` methods though.

Comment: How would you override a protected method if you can't add anything to the package where the class lives?

Comment: You can override `protected` methods even if your custom class isn't in the same package as the super class. Perhaps you're confusing `protected` with package-private (i.e. no access modifier).